# Error when trying to upload an image to Microsoft Azure

Tags: azure, cloud

I'm trying to upload an image to my container name "vhds" inside storage account "pruebasatfacr" but I'm getting the following error:

[root@vm49 KVM]# azure storage blob upload -a pruebasatfacr -k "$base64string"  --container vhds

info:    Executing command storage blob upload

File name: azure-POSTGRES-9.3.2-RHEL-65.X64.ATF.PRB-disk1.vdh

- Checking blob azure-POSTGRES-9.3.2-RHEL-65.X64.ATF.PRB-disk1.vdh in container vhds

error:   getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND

info:    Error information has been recorded to azure.err

error:   storage blob upload command failed

[root@vm49 KVM]# cat azure.err

Fri Jan 02 2015 09:07:47 GMT+0100 (CET):

{ [Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND]

stack: [Getter/Setter],

code: 'ENOTFOUND',

errno: 'ENOTFOUND',

syscall: 'getaddrinfo',

__frame:

{ name: '__1',

```
 line: 270,

 file: '/usr/lib/node_modules/azure-cli/lib/util/storage.util._js',

 prev:

  { name: 'StorageUtil_performStorageOperation__1',

    line: 251,

    file: '/usr/lib/node_modules/azure-cli/lib/util/storage.util._js',

    prev: [Object],

    active: false,

    offset: 19,

    col: 4 },

 active: false,

 offset: 2,

 col: 15 },
```

rawStack: [Getter] }

Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND

```
at errnoException (dns.js:37:11)

at Object.onanswer [as oncomplete] (dns.js:124:16)

at __1 (/usr/lib/node_modules/azure-cli/lib/util/storage.util._js:272:15)

at StorageUtil_performStorageOperation__1 (/usr/lib/node_modules/azure-cli/l

at uploadAzureBlob (/usr/lib/node_modules/azure-cli/lib/commands/asm/storage
```

I guess that can be a DNS issue but I need more information about that, does anyone know why can it be caused?

Thanks in advance!

PS: I'm using 0.8.13 CLI version

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this issue on CentOS-based machines running inside of Azure - it's actually a locking issue inside node.js which the Azure x-plat CLI relies on.

I've found if you keep on retrying the command you will eventually be successful (more by luck than by anything else).

See the github bug report: https://github.com/joyent/node/issues/7729